# Remote modal works on Bootstrap 3.0.0rc1 but doesn't in 3.0.0 final

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I found this example working on 3.0.0 rc1

http://plnkr.co/edit/HWSgSw?p=preview

But when I change it to point to 3.0.0 final it stop working. Why? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
<a href="first.html" data-target="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal">Launch First</a>
<a href="second.html" data-target="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal">Launch Second</a>
```

with

```
<a href="#myModal" data-target="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal">Launch First</a>
<a href="#myModal" data-target="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal">Launch Second</a>
```

Comment: I as mention it, I would like to display remote data. Thanks